# In procedure scm_lreadr: #<unknown port>:1:42: end of file in string constant

Tags: scheme, guile

I am writing test code using guile/scheme and i tried to extract each line of a text file as a string and used `(eval-string str)` to evaluate the expresion in the string. But, i get `In procedure scm_lreadr: #<unknown port>:1:42: end of file in string constant`
 error. So, how can i remove the end of file `#<eof>` object from the end of the string i want to evaluate using `(eval-string str)`. Here is the sample code

```
(define (test-func)
(call-with-input-file "tests.txt"
    (lambda (port)
(while #t
  (let ((line (get-line port)))
  (if (eof-object? line) (break))
  (set! line (string-trim line))
  (display (format #f "-> ~a\n"line))
  (set! line (string-trim (substring line 1)))
  (display (format #f "~a\n" line))
  (eval-string line)
)))))
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's not a problem in the line you're evaling?

Comment: no, i can run the same line `(eval-string line)` if i supplied the string directly instead of extracting it from file.

Comment: in my opinion the problem is that line read from a file ends with `<#eof>` object.